# Matplotlib errorbar lines covered by data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting two data sets here with matplotlib, one of which (red) is to show typical errors. The lines, however, are plotted underneath the data points of the other (crowded) set and therefore get hidden. Is there a way to force the errorbar lines to be on top?

Here's what I have:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ko', markersize=0.5)
ax.errorbar([0]*len(err_yvals), err_yvals, xerr=xerrors, yerr=yerrors, 
             fmt='o', c='red', ms=3, elinewidth=1)
fig.tight_layout()
```

And [here's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qGz1.png) (I'd like the red errorbar points to always be on top):

Comment: Try adding the `zorder=3` argument to your call to `errorbar`. See here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with some simulated data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

data = np.random.rand(10000, 2)
xdata, ydata = data[:,0], data[:,1]

err_yvals = [0.5]* 3
xerrors = 0.3
yerrors = 0.3

ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ko', markersize=2)
ax.errorbar([0.5]*len(err_yvals), err_yvals, xerr=xerrors, yerr=yerrors, 
             fmt='o', c='red', ms=10, elinewidth=2, zorder=3)
fig.tight_layout()
```

With the `zorder=3` argument the error bars are plotted on top of the points.

[image]